# Give a simple hash chain example in Java

Tags: hash

I am looking for a very simple example of cryptography hash chain source code. Could you forward me some examples or link, guys?
For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain [1].
`h(h(h(h(x))))` gives a hash chain of length 4. h=hash, x=password

Comment: Cannot understand hash-chain without source codes

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a programming question and no crypto question.

Comment: You'd need a salt as well to be reasonably secure for passwords. Use a PBKDF such as PBKDF2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Java programmer, and I didn't compile this, but I modified answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/how-can-i-generate-an-md5-hash) to achieve a hash chain of length equal to four.

```
byte[] bytesOfMessage = yourString.getBytes("UTF-8");

MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

byte[] thedigest = md.digest(md.digest(md.digest(md.digest(bytesOfMessage))));
```

PS. Don't use MD5 for crypto. It's not secure.

Comment: So why do you use MD5 in your example?

Comment: I didn't want to change the sources in any other way then adding the chain to allow everyone easy way of spotting the differences between my answer and the linked one.